# Access Child elements in Protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to access text attribute of child element but every time getting null value. The DOM looks like as below

```
<div ng-repeater='abc'>
    <span class='xyz'>Mango</span>
</div>
<div ng-repeater='abc'>
    <span class='xyz'>Apple</span>
</div>
```

I have tried below code:

```
   var parent = element(by.repeater('abc'));
    var child = parent.all(by.xpath('//span[@class="xyz"]'));

    for (let index = 0; index < parent.count(); index++) {
      console.log("Value" + child.getText());
    }
```

All the time im getting the error as `Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

I have already tried increasing the timeout to 30seconds and the page is loading properly with no sync issues but still getting the error.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you want to access via parent when you can access it via one xpath(without separate elements for parent and child)

Comment: @AaryaHareendranath no specific reason i even tried directly with element.all(child element locator) but the thing is i'm getting no output in the console due to continue async issues. if you can help me with this issue may be i'll be able to see some output in my console.

Answer (score 2):

```
element.all(by.repeater('abc')).getText().then(function(txts){
   txts.forEach(function(txt){
      console.log(txt);
   })
})

// the `getText()` api will get visible text of all descendants of current element, 
// that's why parent node `div` can get the text on child node `span`
```

Comment: It worked. Please help me understand the code as i'm not able to understand how come parent element's text u r able to fetch?

Comment: @SandeepRaulo `.count()` returns a promise, so you cant use it in loops directly